# Is it possible to add the tablename to a select statement from a textbox value

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I am using Visual Studio 2008 and SQL Server 2008.
I am trying to give the tablename from a textbox value as follows:

```
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("select * from '"+Textbox1.Text+"'", conn);
```

But I am not getting any results.

Please help me. What have I done wrong here?

Comment: what error are you getting??

Comment: Error was I get no selected table and my dear friend thank you for solving and I won't use it in that way. But this was a simple programme. Thanks alot :)

Comment: This is bad, bad, bad news. Why are you letting users dictate which table they're going to select all columns and all rows from? Never mind the SQL injection problems here, yikes, this sounds like a disaster waiting to happen.

Comment: Actually it's a combobox which is having the employee category such as Accountant, Manager, Receptionist...etc. So the combobox filled with values when the form is loaded. This gives me the opportunity to select each employee table and display them in a datagridview as they have different tables in the DB :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the questions:

When in Studio you need to execute the command by calling

```
sqlConn.Open();
sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM " + Textbox1.text + "", sqlConn);
sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
sqlConn.Close();
```

But:

Read up on SQL Injection this is not safe at all.

Answer (score 1):

You are enclosing the table name in single quotes and you shouldn't. But besides that,you are vulnerable to [SQL Injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Do NOT, ever, use string concatenation to build sql statements.

Your code would work (BUT DON'T USE THIS) if you do:

```
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("select * from "+Textbox1.Text+"", conn);
```